# How to define json data as X and Y sklearn decision tree arrays

Tags: python, json, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Suppose my data consist of fruits, described by their color and shape and more features (texture size peel type etc) with arbitrary values.

I would like to fit my data to a decision tree using [sklearn.tree](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/tree.html#classification)

How do I build a decision tree in sklearn.tree. What is the samples and features array defined by X and what is Y. 
For the DB I use mongodb therefore the dataset is in json:

`{"_id":2323, "shape":"round", "color":[red,green], "texture":"A", "pill":"X", "more":[1,2,3]}`

`{"_id":2324, "shape":"round", "color":[orange], "texture":"C", "pill":"", "more":[1,2]}`

Is there a tutorial for fitting/convert data to python datatype needed for building a decision tree in sklearn.tree?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [documentation on feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html).

**Edit**: I just noticed that you have nested structures in your json construct. The `DictVectorizer` and `FeatureHasher` classes both expect flat dictionaries as input. You can flatten you constructs yourself, for instance to have:

```
{"_id": 2323, "shape": "round", "color/red": 1 "color/green": 1, "texture": "A",
 "pill": "X", "more/1": 1, "more/2": 1, "more/3": 1}
```

And then call `DictVectorizer` or `FeatureHasher` on a list of such flat python dicts.